# Does "one moment " function as an adverb phrase?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> "In today's Maths class, ***one moment*** he says two and three is five. But the next moment he says one and four is five." Mike answers.

I think the sentence mentioned above is not that authentic. I wonder whether the native speaker will use it like this.

Is "one moment" omitted from "for one moment"? If not, can a noun phrase function as an adverb?

Answer (score 7):

It is a commonly used phrase for native speakers. It is not a shortened version of "for one moment." It can be considered a shortened version of "at one moment." "One moment" is equivalent to "one time" or "once." It has no duration.  "For one moment" has the duration of a moment, which is not a specific duration, and certainly is not long, but it *is* a duration.

Comment: Oops, it looks like I accidentally downvoted this instead of upvoting.  I put in a nonce-edit so I could fix that!